# JavaScript method to write to Microsoft Visual Web Developer Debugger?

Tags: javascript, logging, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

I generally test my web apps with Firefox and use Firebug. I love Firebug. But when I'm testing JavaScript code in IE I use the debugger in Microsoft's Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition. I would love to have an equivalent to Firebug's console.log methods which would allow me to log messages to Visual Web Developer. Any way to log messages to the error list/messages list/output pane using JavaScript?

Comment: @john Saunders: Thanks for fixing spelling and tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8's Web Developer tools support console.log when you're debugging your site. I'm not aware of any equivalent for VWD.

Comment: Wow, that's great, that will be a huge help. Thank you!

Comment: Didn't exactly answer my question but nobody else is, so I'll accept as correct. The IE8 Web Developer tools are great.